# Reading Avro file from a GCS bucket using dataflow as PCollection<TableRow>

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I wanted to know how can we read the content of Avro file from GCS as PCollection
I'm trying like this:

```
public static PCollection<TableRow> avroFileReader(Pipeline pipeline,String inputAvroFile){
pipeline.apply("Read Avro from GCS ", AvroIO.__________________) #<-this part is my question
        .apply("Convert Avro to TableRow", ParDo-logic)
}
```

where inputAvroFile is my bucket path that I am getting from dataflow options

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```java
    pipeline.apply("Read Avro from GCS ", AvroIO..parseGenericRecords(new SerializableFunction<GenericRecord, TableRow>() {
           public genRec2TableRow apply(GenericRecord record) {
             // You could produce and return TableRow here
             TableRow tr = BigQueryAvroUtils.convertGenericRecordToTableRow(record, record.getSchema());
             return tr;
           }
         }));
```

You don't need the `ParDo`, you can produce the `TableRow` directly from the parsing function.

Reference: [AvroIO reading records of unknown schema](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html#:%7E:text=Reading%20records%20of%20an%20unknown%20schema)